# Responsive Navbar: Sub-Items overlapping Itembar

Tags: html, css, navigation

**Introduction to clearify the task**

I have a Navbar on the left side of my page. It has two levels for Items. When it's displayed in a small device, only the icons of the first level are shown. If you hover over it a dropdown of sub-items wil be shown on the right side of the bar. So far so good.

[image]

When the user uses a normal device the first-level-items should be displayed as dropdown-headers and the sub-items should expand under their parent-items on click. So I planned to set the sub-items-container under the main-items with `height: 0px;` and exband it with javascript-onclick and a css transition.

[image]

But as you can see the sub-items are hovering over the main item.

**Question**

How can i ensure that the subitemlist is between the main-items and not over it?
 Additionally the solution shouldn't destroy the responsivness.

*Note: I really want to make my own navbar, so using Bootstrap is not an option. Also i'm sorry if the code is not the best, it's the first try.*

**Code**

[I have put the whole thing in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLe61ngg/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant put it in sidebaritem you have to put it below it

Comment: so simple, so effective